# Is const array in java script behaves like const array in C in memory allocation and assignment behaviour?

Tags: javascript, arrays, c, memory, memory-management

In C, the following code allocates two string literals in `.rodata` section. `arr[0]="ABC";` allocates another string literal in `.rodata` then assigning its address to `arr[0]`.

```
const char *arr[2]={"1234", "5678"}
arr[0]="ABC";                      
puts(arr[0]); //ABC
```

In javaScript, Does the following code snippet behaves like the previous?

```
const arr=['1234', '5678'];
arr[0]='ABC';
console.log(arr[0]); //ABC
```

Answer (score 3):

> In javaScript, Does the following code snippet behaves like the previous?

Yes, roughly, but C and JavaScript are generally **very** different despite some superficial syntax similarity, and there are other uses of `const` that aren't things JavaScript's `const` does. For instance, if you'd used `char * const arr[2]={"1234", "5678"}` (which wouldn't let you reassign `arr[0]`), there's no way to use JavaScript's `const` to do that. (You can do something like it, just not with `const`: `const arr = Object.freeze(["1234", "5678"]);`)

**All** that `const` means in JavaScript (vs. `let`)¹ is that you can't change the contents of the variable `arr`. You can change the state of the array `arr` refers to, but you can't make `arr` refer to a different array (or something else entirely).

That is, you can do what you showed in your question:

```js
const arr=['1234', '5678'];
arr[0]='ABC';
console.log(arr[0]); //ABC
```

..but you can't do this:

```js
const arr=['1234', '5678'];
arr = ["ABC"]; // TypeError: Assignment to constant variable
console.log(arr[0]);
```

The only effect it has on memory management is that if the scope where `const` appears is long-lived (like global or module scope), the array your constant refers to can't be released until the scope is destroyed. With `let` you could assign something else to the variable and then the array could be garbage collected. Typically you only use `const` in a long-lived scope for things you want to have around "forever." But const in a short-lived scope (such as a function call that doesn't create closures) doesn't have that implication; when the scope goes away, any  objects referenced by the scope's bindings and not referenced by anything else become garbage-collectable.

---

¹ vs `var` it also means that it has block scope and participates in the TDZ, like `let` does. `const` and `let` are identical other than that `const` creates something immutable. `var` is different from `const` and `let` (and has no place in modern JavaScript code).

Comment: @NAND - Sorry, I misread your C example (despite it being very clear and simple -- my bad!). I've fixed the opening paragraph. :-)